# Count of Request to Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I have asp.net web Service which is running 5 different version on IIS. I want to calculate count of request every service and also theirs methods for stop unused services.

Could you offer any solution?

Thnx

Note: I have only codes of last version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those versions you do not have the source code for, enable logging on IIS.

For the version you do, you could implement logging, tracing, performance counters...

Basically, there are lots of options, pick one or more and put it to use.